# Getting kernel panics on Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, kernel-panic, kernel-extensions

I am getting kernel panics on reboots for a few weeks now. They seem to be caused by an Oracle kernel extensions(I will add an image of the stacktrace). 
I am using a MacBook Pro 15" retina mid 2014 model with MacOS Sierra.

I assumed that it was caused by VirtualBox, however I uninstalled it and removed the kext with their script and I ran in a kernel panic once again. 
I scanned my SSD with the Disk Utility tool and it showed no errors. Reinstalling MacOS helps temporarily until I restart again.

I appreciate your help.

*Attempt to clean up photo*

[image]

*[original here for ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYHlg.jpg)*

Comment: The oracle kext is still there...

Comment: At the very top of your kernel panic is the message "page fault" which points to a memory issue.  I would at minimum run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.    Also, try removing 1 of the SO-DIMMs and see if the problem goes away.  If not, swap SO-DIMMs and slots to see if there's any change.

Comment: The apple hardware test did not show any errors. Also, I won't be able to remove the SO-DIMMs since they are fixed on the motherboard on mac version 11.3.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have searched in /Library/Extensions and /System/Library/Extension for this specific Oracle kext however I can't find it there...

Comment: @Allan - not that I'm any kind of expert on the inner workings of memory - but isn't a page fault usually just a memory call that needed to be called from pagefile - or does that no longer apply once we're in panic & at that point it must be an actual invalid condition which cannot be handled, an address that simply doesn't exist?

Comment: @DimitriTyan - they can be in other places too. The surest way to find them is to get [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) (freeware) Set search for .kext [inc the. ], entire boot drive,  only files, all words, ignore case, + invisibles. That will find things that Spotlight certainly won't. [it's quite slow, but it's good]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the Kernel Panic by formatting my hard drive and reinstalling my OS.